# Adding icon to product added in cart PHP/Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to add a checkmark to the products that have been added to cart.
I am using ajax to return.
But i know i am doing wrong.
I got a bit lost.
I made with php first,and it works,but only displays when i refresh the page.
My php code...

```
if(isset($_SESSION['product'][$id])){
    $added='<a href="" class="badge-corner" product_id="'.$id.'" >
    <span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>';
    }else{
    $added='';
    }
```

I want to use ajax to display the checkmark.

[image]

This is where i get my product id and store them to session.
My add to cart function and item counter code..(cart_function2.php)

```
  <?php header('Content-Type: application/json');

session_start();
 if (isset($_GET['action'])) {

  $action = $_GET['action'];
  $prod   = $_GET['prod_id'];
  $result="";

  switch ($action) {

    case 'add':
        $result = add_prod($prod);
    break;

    default:
        $result = ['result'=>'error'];
    break;
  }



}
// Calculate subtotal here
$result['totals'] = new stdClass;
$total_in_cart=count($_SESSION['product']);  
$_SESSION['products']=$total_in_cart;
if(isset($_SESSION['product'][$prod])){
$added='<a href="" class="badge-corner" product_id="'.$prod.'"  ><span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>';
}else{
    $added='';
}

$result['added'] = $added;
$result['items'] =  $total_in_cart; 

 echo json_encode($result);

function add_prod($prod){
  //add function
$_SESSION['product'][$prod] = 1;
$_SESSION['products']++;

return ['result'=>'success'];
}



?>
```

And this is the script in my gallery...

```
$('.actions').click(function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(e);
  var action = $(this).attr('data-action'); //gets button id
  var id = $(this).attr('product_id');
  console.log("triggered action " + action + " for product " + id); 

  $.ajax({
  url: 'cart_functions2.php',
  type : 'GET',
  data: {action:action,prod_id:id},
  dataType: 'json'

}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("ajax call returned the following: " + JSON.stringify(data));

  if (data.result == "success") {

$("#items").html(data.items);
$(".show").html(data.added) + id;
//some debugging script
```

i am trying to display in here

```
<div class="show">'.$added.'</div>
```

When i click  add product, all my products gets checked at once.
Why? 
Please help me,i'm still a noob at jquery.

Comment: The code for cart functions 2? You are using that part of the code, but not showing it... are you sure that cart_functions2.php returns "success" to the  ajax request?

Comment: where in the code is the element with id items?

Comment: i get this from console........ajax call returned the following: {"result":"success","totals":{},"added":"<a href=\"\" class=\"badge-corner\" product_id=\"171\"  ><span class=\"fa fa-check\"></span></a>","items":1}

Comment: this is the most important parts of the code

Comment: You mean where is the elements with item ids? if so ,all products are coming from a while loop